# List layout in Android like unordered HTML list

Tags: android, html, xml

I create app with recipes, and I need to show ingredients this way:

- Coffee
- Tea
- Milk

i.e. like in html

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

And the actual question: is there a way to do this?

I want to avoid creating around 10 `TextViews` for this goal. Or do I really need to create simple `ListView` and add to every item with a "point" before every list item title?

Comment: If you want to write a native app, you'll need a ListView. If you're going to write an hybrid app, then you could do it in HTML/Javascript then use a WebView

Comment: Use `BulletSpan` as part of building up a `SpannedString`, and use that in one `TextView`. Or use a `WebView`. Or use the `ListView` approach that you outline. Or use a `RecyclerView` in the same fashion as you are thinking of for your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom list item layout having `ImageView` and `TextView` and inflate that layout in simple adapter.

For more see : [ListView with Images and Text using Simple Adapter in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/)

Or as @CommonsWare suggested,you may use `RecyclerView`

see : [Android Simple RecyclerView Widget Example](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-recyclerview-widget-example/)